# CSS element appearing in wrong place

Tags: css

I have the following sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left_nav">1 2 3</div>

    <div class="body_main">
        <div class="top_nav_right">Create account Log in</div>

        <div class="top_nav">
            <span>Article Talk</span> <span class="top_nav_right2">Read
                Edit View history</span>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my CSS:

```
.body_main {
    margin-left: 11em;
}


.top_nav_right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.top_nav {
    height: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}


.top_nav_right2 {
    float: right;
}
```

I'm not sure why "Create account Log in" appears below "Read Edit View history".  Those are both divs and I have the Read one following the Create one.

Also, for some reason, only Chrome displays the CSS.  I have put the CSS in a validator

Comment: does it? http://jsfiddle.net/NVT8A/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not clearing your floats.

When you float `.top_nav_right`, it creates a void of space that elements below it are going to try to fill.  Since you floated it to the right, the extra space will be on the left of `.top_nav_right`, which will make `.top_nav` and it's contents appear on the left (or before).

To fix this, you can simply clear the float produced by `.top_nav_right` by adding the following CSS definition to `.top_nav`

```
clear: both;
```

You can see the results of the clear here: http://jsfiddle.net/P7QTC/2/

You can learn more about the Why's and How's of clearing floats properly here: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Additionally, you need to be sure to close all of your `<div>` tags.  I noticed that `.body_main` is missing a closing tag.

Comment: Thanks I made those corrections but I still see "Article Talk" and "Read.." on the same line. I want Article and Create sections on the same line, below "Create"

Comment: My apologies.  I forgot to add the clear in the JSfiddle.  You can find the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/P7QTC/2/

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that your `<link>` type is incorrect. It should read `type="text/css"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to close the div tag of the div with the class 'body_main'